# Windows Live USB doesn't show up in boot device options

Tags: boot, usb

I went ahead and wiped my hard drive then installed Ubuntu 15.04. For a while, it worked fine but I need to get back to Windows 8/10. I made a USB drive to replace the recovery CD. But I am unable to get it running and install Windows. My computer is a HP Notebook Stream 13.
How can I install Windows another way or make the recovery USB show up?